# Python/Sklearn - Back log transform y variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new to ML models and need help. I've log transformed the y variable using np.log function and have derived the coefficients and Actuals and Predicted values as below -

```
#Linear Reg fit 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression  
regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)  

coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])  
coeff_df 

# Predictions
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)  
results = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})  
results
```

and I'm getting the following results

## Output Coefficients:

X1      0.001298

X2      0.021810

X3      0.000666

## Actual  Predicted

3.583519   4.916827

5.746203   7.110532

8.099251   7.573847

I want to be able to back transform the values, so I can compare the actuals to predicted in original scale, Can you please advice on how I should go about the back transform

Thanks,
SV

Comment: Please add that part where you transformed the `y`.

Comment: I used the below function to transform/ get log of y variable         
df['logy'] = df['y'].apply(np.log)

Comment: And `y_train` is made from that `df['logy']`?

Comment: Yes Vivek, y_train is made from df['logy']

Comment: Well then, try `np.exp(y_pred)` to get actual results.

Comment: I wasnt sure if I could apply exponent function to y_pred directly, or if i should apply exponent function to the right equation ( i.e. Since Log y = (const + b1x1 + ... + bnxn) ) ; Would it make sense to apply the exp function to right side of the equation

Comment: Yes. The y_train you sent will be used to fit to `const + b1x1 + ... + bnxn`. And hence the results will be from that.